# Cancel WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown if not clicked

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm using `WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown` and `WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerUp` within a WinJS repeater's item template.

The problem is if a user holds their finger or the mouse button down on an item and moves off it, the pointerUp animation doesn't seem to fire or it fires but has no effect because the element that the up event is on is not the same as the one before. The best example of this is in the [animation sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/using-the-animation-787f3720) in example 6 (tap and click). Hold down the mouse button on a tile and move it off. It will stay in it's animated state and won't fire the pointerup event. Here's the code I'm using.

How can I cancel the pointerdown animation if the user moves off the element?

```
target1.addEventListener("pointerdown", function () {

    WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown(this);

}, false);


target1.addEventListener("pointerup", function () {

    WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerUp(this);

}, false);


target1.addEventListener("click", function () {

    //do something spectacular

}, false);
```

I'm using the click event to commit the click action so that the right click remains clear for launching the navigation at the top of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding an event listener for pointerout?  That's the event that's dispatched when  a pointing device (e.g. mouse cursor or finger) is moved out of the hit test boundaries of an element.

See the docs on pointer events here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772103(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I didn't realise there was a pointer out event.